# decode a video with nvdecode (nvidia video sdk 7.1) and ffmpeg

Tags: nvidia, ffmpeg, sdk

How can I enable and use **nvdecode**(nvidia video sdk 7.1) with **ffmpeg** to decode a video??

thank you

Answer (score 2):

According to [FFmpeg Wiki: Hardware Acceleration](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#CUDACUVIDNvDecode):

> CUVID offers decoders for H264, HEVC, MJPEG, mpeg1/2/4, vp8/9, vc1.
>   Codec support varies by hardware. The full set of codecs being
>   available only on Pascal hardware, which adds VP9 and 10 bit support.
>
> Sample decode using CUVID which copies the frames to system memory in
>   this case:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i input output.mkv
> ```
>
> Full hardware transcode with CUVID and NVENC:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow output.mkv
> ```
>
> Partial hardware transcode, with frames passed through system memory
>   (this is necessary for transcoding 10bit content):
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i input -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow output.mkv
> ```
>
> If ffmpeg was compiled with support for libnpp, it can be used to
>   insert a GPU based scaler into the chain:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input -vf scale_npp=-1:720 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow output.mkv
> ```
>
> The `-hwaccel_device` option can be used to specify the GPU to be used
>   by the cuvid hwaccel in ffmpeg.